# Invalid MailChimp List ID - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, mailchimp, api-key

i'm gotting this error from my web page, when i try to go to "localhost:3000/suscribir" i got this error:

```
Missing template subscribe/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:es, :en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

this is my routes.rb file...

```
  post '/suscribir' => 'subscribe#create'
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: Refinery::Core.mounted_path
```

this is the subscribe controller...

```
class SubscribeController < ApplicationController
  def create
    logger.info "suscripcion #{params.inspect}"
    user = user_params(params)
    MailchimpWrapper.subscribe(user, params[:group_name], params[:group])
    redirect_to '/gracias'
  rescue Mailchimp::Error => e
    logger.error "ERROR mailchimp #{e.message} #{params.inspect}"
  end

  private

  def user_params(params)
    user = {
      email: params[:email].try(:downcase),
      first_name: params[:first_name].try(:titleize),
      last_name: params[:last_name].try(:titleize),
      city: params[:city].try(:titleize),
      phone: params[:phone],
      comment: params[:comment].try(:titleize)
    }
    user
  end
end
```

You can check the line "`redirect_to '/gracias'`"

and this is the gracias.html.erb :

```
<section class="container thanks-subscribe">
  <span>Gracias por suscribirte!</span>
  <p>Si es la primera vez que te registras a nuestra lista de contactos, revisa tu correo. Te estaremos enviando un correo de confirmación</p>
  <a href="/home"><button>Regresa a la página principal y sigue navegando</button></a>
</section>
```

without rescue from mailchimp i got this error..

```
SyntaxError in SubscribeController#create
C:/Sites/ifurniture/app/controllers/subscribe_controller.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

so i edited the subscribe_controller.rb it looks:

```
class SubscribeController < ApplicationController
  def create
    logger.info "suscripcion #{params.inspect}"
    user = user_params(params)
    MailchimpWrapper.subscribe(user, params[:group_name], params[:group])
    redirect_to '/gracias'
  end

  private

  def user_params(params)
    user = {
      email: params[:email].try(:downcase),
      first_name: params[:first_name].try(:titleize),
      last_name: params[:last_name].try(:titleize),
      city: params[:city].try(:titleize),
      phone: params[:phone],
      comment: params[:comment].try(:titleize)
    }
    user
  end
end
```

and gives me this error:

```
Mailchimp::Error in SubscribeController#create
You must provide a MailChimp API key
```

this is the mailchimp_wrapper.rb file:

```
module MailchimpWrapper
  def self.subscribe(user, group_name = nil, group = nil)
    mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
    merge_vars = merge_vars_hash(user, group_name, group)
    mailchimp.lists.subscribe(
      ENV['MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID'],
      { email: user[:email] },
      merge_vars, 
      'html', 
      true, 
      true, 
      false, 
      false
      )
  end
```

i set te ENV API_KEY and the List ID, but now i'm getting this error..

```
Mailchimp::ListDoesNotExistError in SubscribeController#create
Invalid MailChimp List ID:
```

I check and the data is correct, the API and the ID list... in MailChimp in the logs I saw the error `200 List_DoesNotExist`

Comment: Would you mind posting what `logger.info` and `logger.error` show?

Comment: Do you have the `MAILCHIMP_API_KEY` environment variable set?

Comment: Wasn't setted, i do it and now i got this error 

`Mailchimp::ListDoesNotExistError in SubscribeController#create
Invalid MailChimp List ID: `

and the list ID is the correct.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rescue from `Mailchimp::Error` and see what you're actual error is.

In your rescue, you're not redirecting or rendering anything which means it will try to render the template for the action, which in your case is `create` on `subscribers`.

Comment: i delete the rescue and i got that error:


`SyntaxError in SubscribeController#create
C:/Sites/ifurniture/app/controllers/subscribe_controller.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: I modified the syntax and now i got this problem 
`Mailchimp::ListDoesNotExistError in SubscribeController#create Invalid MailChimp List ID:` and the list ID is the correct

Answer (score 0):

wrong syntax dude

```
  def create
    begin
      logger.info "suscripcion #{params.inspect}"
      user = user_params(params)
      MailchimpWrapper.subscribe(user, params[:group_name], params[:group])
      redirect_to '/gracias'
    rescue Mailchimp::Error => e
      logger.error "ERROR mailchimp #{e.message} #{params.inspect}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: The issue continues, is not problem of syntax.

Comment: I missed read it, did you add a create template ? otherwise you should for render(:new) because it's not finding any template linked with the route

Comment: i resolved the missing template removing the rescue from mailchimp, but now i am getting "invalid list ID"